# Force footer to stay at bottom CSS

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I've been messing around with CSS but I still can't get a "sticky footer" to work for some reason.

If there's not enough content, the footer works correctly and stays at the bottom, however, if there's a lot of content the last 100px is always behind the footer when it shouldn't be and I cant figure out why.

To see what happens visit: http://hevvo.eu/~dev/backtrack/index.php

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks fine to me what is the problem? And is it only in certain browsers? Looks good on Firefox 15.0.1

Comment: I'm using Firefox, I've also used Chrome and it doesn't work in there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of articles about this. My favorite one is:

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Comment: Indeed, and that's what I was using ;) but it still doesn't work correctly

Comment: It only works when there's little content, once there's a full page of content, it hides behind the footer, rather than pushing the footer down the last 100px or so.

Comment: Just add **padding-bottom: 100px;** to the #wrapper element.

Comment: Was supposed to say "see", not "seem"

Comment: Visit the above link with caution - it appears to have turned in to a pit of evil since the comment was posted

Answer (score 2):

From CSS-tricks: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

CSS:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; } 

html, body, #wrap { height: 100%; }

body > #wrap {height: auto; min-height: 100%;}

#main { padding-bottom: 150px; }  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer { 
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;
} 

/* CLEAR FIX*/
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%;}
.clearfix { display: block;}
/* End hide from IE-mac */
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="main" class="clearfix">

    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>
```

Comment: This is a lot of unnecessary extra css in my opinion.

Comment: True, but when you are dealing with cross-browser conformity and presentation, CSS always bloats.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to set a `padding-bottom: (height-of-footer)px` on the `.wrapper`. Once you set that, it works just fine. I.e:

```
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #F7F4EB;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Comment: No, I didn't because when that padding is set and there's little content, the padding is visible and looks ridiculous, it also doesn't fix it for when there's a lot of content too...

Comment: It did work for me with lots of content, but you are right, it does look weird with little content.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding a new div around the content and adding a padding-bottom: 100px; to it.